# How to preserve generated content after back button pressed?

Tags: asp.net

There is some generated contents with the links on an ASP.NET page, which is created after the user inputs values and hits a button. The links take the user to another page.

When the user hits the `Back` button, the generated content is gone as the page returns to its initial state with the inputs cleared and generated content not there.

Is it possible to preserve the state of the page after its content has been generated and restore it after the `Back` button was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can you can you temporary cookies. 
and on load check whether cookie is exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Save the inputs in the session, so that the page will know how to correctly render on later requests. Even better, have the first code that runs when the data is submitted redirect to new page with a URL parameter that you use to know which links to show. This is a called a [POST-REDIRECT-GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

Comment: Will that work? Will there even be a request to the server when the "back" button is pressed?

Comment: @JohnSaunders If the browser was caching a page to show for the button instead of sending a request, the links would still be there and the OP wouldn't have asked the question. But I updated the answer to also recommend post-redirect-get

Comment: `PageLoad` event is not firing when the back button is pressed. What do I need to hook up to in order to regenerae the dynamic content?